# What will be the g-captcha-response after 1 million usage of Google ReCaptchaV2 free ? Will it be an empty string or something else?

Tags: javascript, java, recaptcha, grecaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I am working for a project where I have to integrate google **recaptcha v2** . I am afraid about what happens if the captcha monthly limit exceeds , How will the google response  looks like at that time ? How will I validate for such a scenario ? Basically after 1 million usage is over I have to allow login of the user Has anyone done this thing?

I have written frontend validation basic code till now, if the length of google response is 0 or greater Since I don't know what will be the google response after 1 million quota I am not able to write any code to validate that?

Answer (score 0):

You will not receive an error creating a token with a [call to execute](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-web-pages#user-action), instead you will receive an error when you [create an assessment](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment) using that token after 1 million if you have not set up a billing account.

https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/billing-information

> **When to enable billing**
>
> - To enable and use reCAPTCHA Enterprise on Google Cloud, you do not need to enable billing for your Google Cloud project. However, you need to enable billing for your Google Cloud project in the following scenarios:
> - You want to exceed the free monthly usage limit of reCAPTCHA Enterprise, which is 1 million assessments per month. For more information about the free monthly usage limit, see Pricing.
> - You are about to exceed the free monthly usage limit of reCAPTCHA Enterprise and you want to continue using reCAPTCHA Enterprise to protect your website without breaking your production workload.
>   *Caution: If you do not enable billing for your Google Cloud project, reCAPTCHA Enterprise returns an error for any new request after you reach the free monthly usage limit of reCAPTCHA Enterprise.
>   You want to migrate site keys from the non-Enterprise version of reCAPTCHA to reCAPTCHA Enterprise.*
> - You want to use the password leak detection feature of reCAPTCHA Enterprise.
>
> To learn how to enable billing for your project, see Enable billing for a project.

If you make the call to assessment using the REST endpoint you will get a 429 RESOURCE EXHAUSTED response.

Comment: How will the [g-recaptcha-response] look like in case when someone using a free version of google V2  spends his monthly limit? Will it be an empty string or not?  If it isn't an empty string, I will send this [g-recaptcha-response] for server-side validation  but the problem is then how will the json response looks in that case ? FOR EXAMPLE -  it looks like this in case of success or failure {
  {
  "success": true|false,
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  "hostname": string,    
  "error-codes": [...]

Comment: We are using the free version of google captcha version 2. We are not using a billing account.                                                                                                                          
  What do you mean by a call to execute? Do you mean the captcha widget will be visible? and what do you mean by creating an assessment does that mean the server-side validation will not work google will give 429 RESOURCE EXHAUSTED response